# Realm: Check if query has results or not

Tags: java, android, realm

Many times I'd like to have a Realm query return a boolean that tells wether the query contains results or not. I'm not aware of a Realm built in which serves this purpose so I ended up with two methods:

```
public boolean check(int property) {
    Realm realm = null;
    try {
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        RealmQuery<MyObject> query = realm.where(MyObject.class)
                .equalTo("property", property);
        if (query.findFirst() == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } finally {
        if (realm != null) realm.close();
    }
}
```

OR

```
public boolean check(int property) {
    Realm realm = null;
    try {
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        RealmQuery<MyObject> query = realm.where(MyObject.class)
                .equalTo("property", property);
        if (query.count() < 1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } finally {
        if (realm != null) realm.close();
    }
}
```

They only differ in the `query.findFirst() == null` vs `query.count() < 1` part.
Which of the two is the fastest performance-wise, keeping into consideration the underlying query is usually much more complex than this one?

Comment: I think there's not a big difference in terms of the performance. Anyway, because other reasons (code reading included) I'd use `query.count() == 0` instead.

Comment: Well, I'd say the performance difference is minimal, but `findAll().count() <= 0)` should perform... better?

Comment: I think `query.count() == 0` would be slightly faster since it has less JNI calls. But it should not really have too much notable difference.

Comment: Good point but I was thinking that on a fairly large dataset .findFirst() doesn't need to go through the whole dataset to count all results but could just stop at the first found. This purely is speculation though as that code is not open sourced yet I believe.